# Android client cert authorization only through device

Tags: android

On my server, I need to ensure that I receive connections only from android devices.
Is it possible? To store client cert for this in custom android assembling that is resistant to rooting ? Or I can hide absolutely nothing on rooted device? And can not avoid rooting by any means(for ex providing my own android assembled firmware)?  Cause even if I set program root checking - the app can be rebuilt by 3d party to avoid this check. Any usefull ideas appreciated. Thx in advance.

Comment: What kind of connection are you talking about? Sockets (TCP) or HTTP even? There are ways to harden it for 'hackers' to fake a connection from a different source than an Android device for example, implementing a protocol with your own handshake and if the handshake fails, that you drop the connection immediately before it can do anything else. And for HTTP there are other ways to have this handshake method done. 

So it it's important to know what kind of connection you're talking about.

Comment: Ssl. Certificate means https.

Comment: not completely. SSL certs can be used for secure socket connections as well. But thanks for the info, I would update your question if I were you, providing the rest that the communication is done over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `OAuth2` is authentication and authorization protocol which is broadly used by largest and even smaller companies. Think of Facebook API. If a user is not authentication nor authorized to make that call, you can drop the inbound request. That's one method.

**2)** Second method would be to add your own user agent to your HTTP header and other custom HTTP headers. If your server checks on these headers, then you can drop the inbound requests.

You don't have to store the SSL certificate on the client as the client would initiate a secure connection with the server that has the SSL certificate.

Anyhow, using a certificate client side could be okay to encrypt data but I don't believe Android Java has support for that. Correct me if I'm wrong. If you do happen to encrypt data with that key, you could encrypt a certain String or bytes that you can parse into one of your custom HTTP headers but if someone finds out what the encrypted String would be, he/she can still fake a connection. However I do not recommend to store your SSL certificate on the client's device.

---

Regardless of what you might do, there's always a way to fake a HTTP/HTTPS connection like it's coming from an Android device but you can narrow down the incoming HTTPS requests using these two methods and make it much harder. An example would be Pokémon GO. There are plenty of unofficial APIs on GitHub who can fake a connection like it's coming from the official app.